# How does the default folder change if I run a script in a shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I run

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash homeassistant
source /srv/homeassistant/bin/activate
hass --script check_config
```

the script works as intended, it reads a file called /home/.homeassistant/configuration.yaml

but if I create a shell-script that I run from rc.local:

```
./restart.sh > /tmp/log_restart &
```

restart.sh:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash homeassistant
source /srv/homeassistant/bin/activate
hass --script check_config
```

I get this error:

file does not exist: /root/.homeassistant/configuration.yaml

It seems like the root folder is changed, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that what you're doing at first is all about setting up interactive shells and then working within those.  The `source ...` line doesn't execute until the `sudo` line completes, they aren't run in the same context in the script.

To do this, what you should probably do is put just the `source` and `hass` lines in a script, and in `rc.local` run `su -c /path/to/restart.sh homeassistant`

Since `rc.local` runs as root you shouldn't need the `sudo` part